# How to make a Button smaller?

Tags: java, android, button

I've got a table with a couple of TextViews and two Buttons in each row. But the text in the buttons is much larger than the text in TextViews. How can I make the Buttons smaller?

```
        Button view_button = new Button(this);
        view_button.setText("test");
        tr.addView(view_button);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
view_button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Force it to wrap around the text

Answer (score 0):

By using layout params you can set the height and width for button.

```
Button btnEdit = new Button(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

or

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30,30);

btnEdit.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```